# Best approach on reusing private unlocked packages

Tags: salesforcedx

With the introduction of unlocked packages I, as an employee for a Salesforce partner company, see the viability to use these feature to package reusable solutions that we can use in other clients.

Imagine I want to start a new project but I want to reuse a couple of packages I’ve developed before. I would like to reuse those packages that could be hosted in different repositories than the new package (even maybe a specific version of them).

I’m new to SalesforceDX but from the things I’ve read, in order to have a SalesforceDX project with multiple packages (some of them could be dependant on another) you need to have all of them in the same DX project, therefore the same repository.

Is my reasoning correct? In such case, what is the recommended approach to include “remote” packages (maybe using git submodules) without having to copy-paste the package to another project?

Comment: I recall at DF18, Doug Ayers stated that recommended approach is each package has its own repo

Comment: @cropedy that seems appropiate from my point of view. But what would be the recommended approach to reuse / include said packages in another project that could be composed of many packages? Like a node project that it also has its own repo but through the package.json references other packages that are stored remotely each in their respective repos.